# How to enable touch outside when PopOverView open?

Tags: ios, segue, uipopover

I'm using popover with my app. I want to enable touch outside when popoverview open. For now I can not touch outside of popoverview when i click the outside of popoverview , it disappear.

Here is my screen shot for what i want to do. I use popoversegue in storyboard.

How can i do this issue?

Thanks for helpings.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `passthroughViews` for achieving the same.

```
yourPopoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewToEnableTouch, nil];
```

> `passthroughViews` *Property*
>
> An array of views that the user can interact with while the popover is
>   visible. Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> `var passthroughViews: [AnyObject]?`
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *passthroughViews`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When a popover is active, interactions with other views are normally
>   disabled until the popover is dismissed. Assigning an array of views
>   to this property allows taps outside of the popover to be handled by
>   the corresponding views. Import Statement
>
> import UIKit
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Reference [UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/passthroughViews)

---

If you don't want to dismiss popover when user clicks outside, then you can achieve that through:

```
- (BOOL) popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks.it will do my stuff  but i don't have popovercontroller class. i use popoversegue. How to import this code my project.

Comment: @fozoglu: In the prepare for segue you can get it like : UIPopoverController* popover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue popoverController];

Comment: i get a error viewToEnableTouch -> use of undeclared identifier

Comment: @fozoglu: That's a dummy value I put. You need to put your actual view there (something like self.view)

Comment: Sorry. I am confused. I create simple project. i add two button in storyboard and just one button connect popoversegue. i create two UIViewController class first ViewController second MyPopoverController. Import MyPopoverController in ViewController Here then what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me using SWIFT. It will allow you to interact with the "doneBtn" as well "myMap".

```
@IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

func showPopover() {

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var popOverVC: popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popVC") as popVC

    popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popOverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myMap.frame.width, self.myMap.frame.height)

    if let pop = popOverVC.popoverPresentationController {

        var passthroughViews: [AnyObject]?
        passthroughViews = [doneBtn, myMap]
        pop.passthroughViews = NSMutableArray(array: passthroughViews!)

        pop.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        pop.sourceView = myButton

        pop.delegate = self

        pop.sourceRect = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 10,
            height: 10)
        }

    self.presentViewController(
        popOverVC,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```